# Modal Verbs and Sequence of Tenses

Tags: tenses, past-tense, modal-verbs, sequence-of-tenses, modality

Should the clause “I would/should think” be followed by another also in the past, according to the rules of tense sequence?

1. I should think he was here [I think he is here now].
2. I should think the two of us would be enough for the job [and I still think so].

I ask also because I wouldn’t, for example, say, “Could you tell me what time it *was*?” Does the same rule not apply to the “polite” conditional? Of course if the sentence began with the present tense, I wouldn’t have a problem.

Comment: What rule of tense sequence are you speaking of? Not only is *I should think* not in the past tense (it's in the present tense; the past tense would be *I should have thought*), but *I should think he **will be** here* is just fine. Last, you can quite easily ask *Could you tell me what time it **was**?* That's a question that's very frequently asked by police officers and lawyers.

Comment: Thank you, I was under the impression that a conditional “should think” could be followed by the conditional past, even though no notion of past time needs to be introduced into the clause.

Comment: Note that *should* isn't necessarily conditional. In fact, it often isn't. (And neither of the sentences in the question are conditional.) Here is an example of a *should think* sentence that's followed by a conditional: *I should think that if you had gone to the store, we would have food in the house now.*

Comment: Ok, I am familiar with that sort of construction, but looking at the definition for “I should/would think” from Merriam/Webster, I see it reads, “used to say that one believes that something is true, that a particular situation exists, that something will happen, etc.” So is it just a stronger, or rather more tentative, variation on “I think”?

Comment: Thank you again!